# Memory-effective sound management in Flash

Tags: actionscript-3, audio, memory-management

As far as I've read in the manuals, when you have to play a sound, you need a `Sound` object, and make a temporary `SoundChannel` object that will control the actual playback. I want to know if there is a memory-efficient way of managing those `SoundChannel` objects. So far it seems that these are of "fire-and-forget" type of objects, and the only way to make them semi-persistent is make the call to `Sound.play()` with a really great number of plays. But this approach will not work for one-time sounds, like an arrow shot or a button click, for example. And if I call `SoundChannel.stop()` I can as well discard the object as there is no means to make it resume playing. Is there any solution to not to spawn `SoundChannel` objects like crazy, and to be able to handle both one-time sound plays and infinite-time sounds aka background music?

Comment: My sound controller usually has at least two `SoundChannel` objects initialised (one for music, one for player sfx etc) and any `Sound` objects I'll need. Am I correct in thinking that calling, for example, `mySoundController = myPlayerSound.play()` creates a new temporary `SoundChannel` object?  If so then I guess I face the same issue you do and I'm sorry I can't be of more help, interesting question nonetheless.

Comment: @Sim Yes, the docs say so, and yes, such call creates yet another SoundChannel object.

Comment: And why exactly would you want to make them (semi-)persistent? I mean, what does it matter whether you'd reuse the same SoundChannel object over and over or use a new one each time the sound is played? If you need one to begin with.

Comment: @Creynders I want to eliminate as many GC calls as technically possible. I am kind of a big fan of low-memory models, having started with Turbo Pascal 6.0 with zero heap. Also it does not feel right, that I always need a new object, these are not like diapers after all.

Comment: Throwaway objects are definitely more memory-friendly than persistent ones. And having persistent sound channel objects won't make any difference in the number of GC calls, only in the amount of memory it is continually hogging up (i.e. in a negative way)

Comment: And what's wrong with GC calls anyway? They are your friend, they clean up your mess. They're a bit like mom ;)

Comment: Well, I'm old enough to make my own mess and deal with it myself. And my real mom has a habit of moving something valuable to me to another place which I can't find without her :) I really want to have as much control as possible over my possessions, be it occupied memory or time when my memory should be freed. And it's unpredictable when GC will fire, as it's the same with one's mother's inspection :) While I'm now making a TD, which is wave-based and pretty much turn-based, I don't want GC to interfere with the framerate.

Comment: Also, I would like to know beforehand how much memory I need for my TD, and what are the boundaries to where I can further extend it. Adding different procedurally generated visual effects, sound effects (should I be able to do this), assets, shaders, everything needs memory, and even while modern PCs have a lot of it (2.0GB are a lot for Flash), I would like to allocate enough at once and then avoid getting more, as a means of self-discipline as well as getting a bit of performance.

Comment: If you need such granular control, you'll need to switch to a different environment, I'm afraid. But TBH I've done some potentially pretty CPU-intensive stuff in the past and if you know what you're doing you get speed, low memory usage and smooth animation/sound. Maybe it's just a bit of a different mindset you need to get into. The GC actually does its job rather well. In only a few instances I've had to manually hold on to some objects, just because the GC kicked in at the wrong moment.

Comment: I tend to follow the screenwriter's adagium: come in late, leave early, meaning objects should get initialized late and lazily and should be disposed of ASAP when no longer used. This combined with green threading, object pooling etc for when lightweight isn't lightweight anymore. The SoundChannel is really just a controller, it holds practically nothing, but just manipulates the sound for the duration of it's play, there's no reason I can think of to hold on to them, or reuse them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SoundChannel` is indeed meant to be throw-away, and this kind of heap usage comes with the territory of using a language like ActionScript.

You shouldn't worry about GC usage from sounds - premature optimization is evil! The best you can do is just reuse your `Sound` object instead of creating a new one each play. There shouldn't be much of a GC issue if you are playing a reasonable number of sounds per frame, say, in a game. `SoundChannel`s are lightweight and reference a single copy of the audio data, so they aren't such a big deal. There will probably be much heavier allocations to worry about, such as game objects or bitmaps.

You *could* avoid using `SoundChannel` by dynamically mixing the audio using [SampleDataEvent](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/events/SampleDataEvent.html), but this will certainly have the opposite effect and be much more processor-intensive, not to mention more difficult to code.

If you are really worried about the GC, you could use [System.pauseForGCIfCollectionImminent](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/system/System.html#pauseForGCIfCollectionImminent%28%29%20System.pauseForGCIfCollectionImminent) method to hint the GC to run during a non-intrusive time, such as during a transition in a game.

Comment: Hmm. A good idea about `System.pauseForGCIfCollectionImminent`, I was not aware of this method. I have points in my game where I can do this call pretty safely. And yes, I certainly will reuse `Sound` objects themselves. Okay, this looks fine for me.